# Laravel eloquent with Trashed on relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I need to be able to get a Models Relationship including its soft deleted elements, but only for this 1 instance. I do not want to change the model so that every time I use the relationship it returns all the soft deleted records too.

How can I achieve this?

**User Model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
  public function contacts(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Contacts','user_id','id');
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);
//Need to be able to get the trashed contacts too, but only for this instance and in this function
$user->contacts->withTrashed(); //Something like this
return $user;
```

How can I get the trashed rows only this 1 time inside my controller?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is using `$user->contacts` returns collection of related records of contacts to user, while `$user->contacts()` will make a new query`

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can use `withTrashed` method in different ways.

To associate the call with your relationship you can do as follows:

```
public function roles() {
    return $this->hasMany(Role::class)->withTrashed();
}
```

To use the same in the fly:

```
$user->roles()->withTrashed()->get();
```

For your special scenario:

```
$user->contacts()->withTrashed()->get();
```

Comment: It completely wen't over my head to just run the `withTrashed()` method in the view itself where I am looping over it. Probably the cleanest way to achieve this, thanks!

Comment: How can I filter records when fetching records using withTrashed()?

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-filter-records-when-using-softdelete-withtrashed

Answer (score 41):

You can also eager load them by adding a clause to the `with()` method

```php
$user = User
   ::with(['contacts' => fn($q) => $q->withTrashed()])
   ->findOrFail($id);
```

Comment: You can also do `company.user` for nested relations for example.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the Laravel Documentation on [Querying soft deleted models](http://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models):

```
//The withTrashed method may also be used on a relationship query: 
$flight->history()->withTrashed()->get();
```

The problem is using `$user->contacts` returns collection of related records of contacts to user, while `$user->contacts()` will make a new query.

Comment: How would you go about nested relationships? A belongsToMany B and B hasMany C? I need a way to say "Give me ALL results for A (including trashed) where ALL relations (B and B->C) show trashed elements". Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with:

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);

$user->contacts()->withTrashed()->get(); //get all results

return $user;
```

When you call the relation with `()`, you can append the `withTrashed()` method. After that you need to `get()` the results.